# IBM http server fail over with multiple instances

Tags: httpwebrequest, websphere

I need help in the following situation:

I have two WebSphere application servers and WebSphere HTTP server.
I need to do the following:

1. when a request failed or (get timeout) on one server , Http Server do not foreword the request to the other WebSphere Application Server.

thanks.

Comment: You have the servers defined in a Cluster?

Answer (score 0):

That's a complicated process, not easily explained, there are so many things that could be wrong.  Have you started with the WAS Admin guide?  It has walkthroughs on this proceedure.  Find it here: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247615.html?Open

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response
I have found a solution which is making the value of SystemIOTimeout = -1 on the webserver plugin